# Redesign how closure labels are displayed

Tags: feature-request, design, closed-questions

There are many questions that has a tag (I don't know how to call it) appended at the end of the title when the question is not appropriate or not useful or something. See the image.

[image: tagged title]

I want to suggest to redesign the tag I mentioned into something of its own.

Just like:

- votes have their own place
- answers have their own place
- views have their own place
- body content has its own place
- tags have their own place
- question owner has its own place

While title and its title tags have to share the same space.

I think the space there should be allocated for the title text. So, the title tag should find its own place somewhere to make it looks nicer probably.

Comment: Any specific proposal on how should it look? Both in question view and in question listings?

Comment: No specific design I have thought for it because I am not good at designs so I let you do it the way you want. I just suggest that this place for the title tags is not so well-done perhaps.

Comment: The closure reason needs to be somewhere prominent so that we can quickly see whether or not we're going to look at the question. I suppose it could be prepended to the question title, if that's the sort of thing you're suggesting?

Comment: Maybe something like that would do, yes.

Comment: One advantage of having it in the title is that you can see that it's closed in all views/lists, such as the question page, the active tab, hot questions, ...

Answer (score 11):

I think the problem is that the "**[duplicate]**" is shown in the same font and colour as the rest of the title. That can lead to confusion with poor titles that (wrongly) add the tags at the end of the title. I have also seen several cases where questions (again wrongly) have "**[solved]**" added at the end of the title.

It would be nice for the text saying "**[duplicate]**" or "**[on hold]**" or whatever to be shown in a different colour. So it is text that cannot be part of the real title.

Comment: I would suggest moving it to the start of the title too. When a title is long and wraps it can be easy to miss the labels.

Comment: Good point, @Dave.

Comment: Yes. That's one way of doing it.